# Android Emulator, System UI is not responding

Tags: react-native, android-studio, emulation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHhaU.png)

System UI is not responding when I lunch android emulator and after clicking on close app it is very slow to use.
My system Specs ->

1. POP OS (Ubuntu)
2. 8GB Ram
3. i5 7th gen
4. Nvidia 940mx

Answer (score 3):

**Quick Resolution:**

- Click on your AVD manager
- Select your Emulator and click the **edit** button for your device.
- Choose **Wipe** in the drop down menu.

See illustration below ..

[image]

**Recommended Resolution :**

- Click on the AVD manager .

[image]

- Select your Emulator and click the **edit** button for your device.

[image]

- Select **Hardware** in the Graphics drop down menu.

[image]

For more information on Graphics acceleration see [**Android Studio Developer Guide**](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I was also using an high end device(pixel 3xl) as emulator so that might be the reason for slow.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your AVD manager and click the Down arrow i.e DropDown Icon in the far left where your emulator name is displayed and Do a cold boot but make sure you are not running your device when doing it. It works for me for sometime say for 3-4 hours then I need to do it again I m not able to find the permanent solution to this but it is rather better than wiping down the data which would not work if you are a mobile dev as it would delete the apk it has installed and all that stuff. I hope your problem is resolved. If any of you seeing this comment in future I mean in 2025? Please reply me to see if I m alive! Bye

Comment: please move this from an answer to comment if you don't have an exact answer. Also, see the previous answer on how to format yours. Outline the steps required in bullet form with screenshots is better than sentence form. " If any of you seeing this comment in future I mean in 2025? Please reply me to see if I m alive! Bye". Should be a comment, exclude this from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 64-bit operating system on your computer, you should change emulators architecture(CPU/ABI) from x86 to x86_64. Create a virtual device and choose a system image [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GavA.png)